# getting default user interface from GKPeerPickerController class

Tags: iphone, p2p, gamekit

i am developing an application which needs bluetooth conection of two iPhones.Now this is what i did:

I created a view based application
I included GameKit Framework in my application.
I did not do anything to my app delegate file and in my view controller's view did load method i wrote folowing piece of code

```
[super viewDidLoad];

 mPicker=[[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
 mPicker.delegate=self;
 mPicker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
 mPeers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 mPicker.show;
```

now i expected the default interface to be shown when my application is launched because this is what is written in my didFinishLaunchingWithOption method of applicationdelegate

```
 [window addSubview:viewController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];

 return YES;
```

what else i need to do to make the defaultinterface visible.I have implemented delegate methods of GKPeerPickerController.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can check this tutorial.This is for chat application but this shows how to display picker
ui.rest part that is related to that you can exclude it.
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/1954

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple bug. This line:

```
mPicker.show;
```

should be:

```
[mPicker show];
```